# Copy activitity Data Factory give 0 on some columns

Tags: azure, copy, azure-data-factory

I have a copy activity in Data Factory which copies data from 1 SQL server to an other one. Tables are identical. Most of the data is copied correctly but starting this week some columns are 0 instead of the original value.

The 0 come from the sourceside, because I've tried many things (like SELECT * FROM table instead of copy a table) and also choose CSV as output. In all cases I receive only 0 for a specific column while there are number in it.

I now see it happen in 2 columns and I'm not 100% sure but I think it was earlier today in 3 columns.

Has somebody ever seen this strange expercience?

Answer (score 0):

> Copy activitity Data Factory give 0 on some columns.

It an unexpected behavior of data factory. I tried and It working fine for me.

***The issue you are facing may have different reasons :***

- **Default Values:** Verify whether the impacted columns default values have been set in the destination table. If a default value of zero is specified for those columns in the destination table, it could be overriding the copied values or` null values if it is getting.

If it is there you can drop it with following command:

```sql
ALTER  TABLE table_name
Drop CONSTRAINT constraint_name
```

- **Incorrect mapping:** Review the mapping settings in your copy activity. Ensure that the column mappings are correctly configured.
- **Data Type Conversion:** Examine the compatibility of the source and destination columns data types. In the event of a mismatch, the copy activity may try to transform the data during copying.

Answer (score 0):

I found out; the issue was that the sourcetable had a masking policy on that column and ADF had no unmasking rights…